# FileNotFoundError when using Julia package from Python

Tags: python, windows, julia

I am trying to run Julia from Python using the Julia package.
After importing the library and installation I run:

```
import julia as jl
jl.install(julia="C:/Users/Name/AppData/local/Programs/Julia/Julia-1.4.1/bin/julia.exe")
```

Then, when I try to create **julia** instance:

```
jl = jl.Julia()
```

I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I specify the execution file again:

```
jl = jl.Julia(runtime = "C:/Users/Name/AppData/local/Programs/Julia/Julia-1.4.1/bin/julia.exe")
```

I get different error message:

```
JuliaError: Exception 'InitError' occurred while calling julia code:
using PyCall
```

How can I solve it?